# Number format pgfplots not changing format

Tags: pgfplots, formatting

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
            yticklabel style={
                    /pgf/number format/.cd,
                        fixed,
                        precision=3,
                        fixed zerofill,
            /tikz/.cd
        },
            }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[   ]
        \addplot coordinates {
        (0.104544882,0.000270831)
        (0.103353608,0.003183656)
        (0.096670185,0.013470824)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And it produces something like this:
[image]

I have tried both

```
/pgf/number format/.cd,
                        fixed,
                        precision=3,
                        fixed zerofill,
            /tikz/.cd
```

And

```
yticklabel style={
                    /pgf/number format/fixed,
                    /pgf/number format/precision=3,
                    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        },
```

And I'm not able to have the y-axis ticks as "0.000, 0.005, 0.010" thus removing that 10^-2 from atop the y-axis. Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Idon't remember the key name but you have to turn off the axis label scaling first

Comment: perfect! the key is /pgfplots/scaled ticks=false. Thanks @percusse

Answer (score 2):

The answer was adding to \pgfplotsset scaled ticks = false.

The code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
        scaled ticks=false,
            yticklabel style={
                    /pgf/number format/.cd,
                        fixed,
                        precision=3,
                        fixed zerofill,
            /tikz/.cd
        },
            }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[   ]
        \addplot coordinates {
        (0.104544882,0.000270831)
        (0.103353608,0.003183656)
        (0.096670185,0.013470824)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]

It is covered in Section 4.15.3 of the Pgfplots manual and it is added to the code in Section 3.2.5. My mistake for overlooking it.